# c++ file parser slow compared to c#

Tags: c++

I need to write a file parser in c++.

Here's my code :

```
std::string line;       
vector<string> slice;

while(getline(m_inputStream, line))  
{           
}
```

My file is big, so this loop takes 12 seconds.

My c# code is :

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName);
string strline = "";

while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    strline = sr.ReadLine();
}
```

And it takes 0.6 seconds... What am I doing wrong in my C++?

Comment: How have you measured? What have you measured? Release or debug? Which compiler, which standard library?

Comment: @izomorphius: for who was your comment?

Comment: Using visual studio as a compiler. And I've just put a timer around the two, so I am measuring the time passed.

Comment: @Simon: The OP, most probably ;)

Comment: What is the optimization options that you selected on your C++ project properties? Also you should measure the performance of your release build, not your debug build.

Comment: The two code snippets are not functually identical. The C++ code, for example, will not run without `m_inputStream` being initialized to an ifstream. The `m_` indicates that it is a class member, so there is more code going on, unrelated to actually stepping through the file line-wise. If you want to benchmark one thing, remove all *other* things first. Perhaps your constructor is sleeping 12 seconds, for all we know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

firstly, what are you doing with `slice`?

Chances are the C# version is reading into the string then discarding it - and the c# JIT is optimising that into a no-op, so the 0.6 seconds it takes is just to initialise and quit. The C++ version will generate code to read the string so it really is processing the input file. Make sure the C++ one is built with Release settings if you're going to compare performance, debug code is meaningless for perf.

Do something with the string and you'll see different performance figures, and also check your memory usage in both systems, the C# one will use up a lot more RAM until the GC kicks in.